# reload data in flutter after adding data

Tags: flutter, dart

guys I just want to know how to reload data from API after doing the post method on darts. I have posted data using the API implementation using providers and models, but after successfully performing the post method, it will be redirected to the first page that contains an index list, but the index list does not display new data that was previously entered, if it is refreshed then the previous data entered can be displayed.
this is how I navigate to the second page on my first page

```
Navigator.push(
 context,
 MaterialPageRoute(
  builder: (context) => TambahSopir(
   text1: widget.idAngkot.toString()
  ),
 )
);
```

this is the second page code to do the post method using the confirmation modal

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:kiriapp/provider/supir.dart';
import 'package:kiriapp/models/supir.dart';
import 'package:dropdown_search/dropdown_search.dart';

class TambahSopir extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text1;
  TambahSopir({Key? key, required this.text1}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<TambahSopir> createState() => _TambahSopirState();
}

class _TambahSopirState extends State<TambahSopir> {
  TextEditingController supir_id = TextEditingController(text: '');
  bool isUploaded = false;
  bool isLoading = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextEditingController angkot_id = TextEditingController(text: widget.text1);
    void showError(String message) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          content: Text(message, textAlign: TextAlign.center),
        ),
      );
    }

    void showSuccess(String message) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          content: Text(
            message,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    var supirProvider = Provider.of<SupirProvider>(context);
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFEFEFEF),
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.white, //change your color here
        ),
        title: Text(
          "Tambah Sopir Angkot",
          style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'PoppinsReg', fontSize: 24, color: Colors.white),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF38AC00),
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 11,
              ),
              Text(
                "Daftarkan Sopir Angkot baru anda sehingga dapat terintegrasi dengan aplikasi ini!",
                style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'PoppinsReg', fontSize: 14),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 21,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 50,
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: supir_id,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    ),
                    filled: true,
                    labelText: 'Id Sopir',
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'PoppinsReg',
                      fontSize: 16,
                    ),
                    hintText: 'Id Sopir',
                    fillColor: Colors.white70,
                    hintStyle:
                        TextStyle(fontFamily: 'PoppinsReg', fontSize: 14),
                    isDense: true, // Added this
                    contentPadding:
                        EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 14.0, top: 14.0, left: 16),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 42,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: double.infinity,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Color(0xff38AC00),
                      onSurface: Colors.black,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10))),
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (supir_id.text.isEmpty) {
                      showError('semua field harus diisi');
                    } else {
                      showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (context) {
                          return AlertDialog(
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                            content: Row(
                              children: [
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Apakah anda yakin ingin mendaftarkan sopir ini?",
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontFamily: 'PoppinsReg',
                                      fontSize: 23,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                            actions: [
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30),
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    ElevatedButton(
                                        child: Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                              left: 20,
                                              right: 20,
                                              bottom: 6,
                                              top: 6),
                                          child: Text(
                                            "Batal",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 18,
                                                fontFamily: 'PoppinsSemBold',
                                                color: Color(0xffF14336)),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                            primary: Colors.white,
                                            onSurface: Colors.black,
                                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                borderRadius:
                                                    BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                                side: BorderSide(
                                                    color: Color(0xffF14336)))),
                                        onPressed: () =>
                                            Navigator.pop(context)),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 12,
                                    ),
                                    ElevatedButton(
                                        child: Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                              left: 30,
                                              right: 30,
                                              bottom: 6,
                                              top: 6),
                                          child: Text(
                                            "Ya",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 18,
                                                fontFamily: 'PoppinsSemBold',
                                                color: Colors.white),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                            primary: Color(0xFF38AC00),
                                            onSurface: Colors.black,
                                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                              borderRadius:
                                                  BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                            )),
                                        onPressed: () async {
                                          setState(() {
                                            isLoading = true;
                                          });
                                          SupirModel? supir =
                                              await SupirProvider.tambah(
                                            supir_id.text,
                                            angkot_id.text,
                                          );

                                          setState(() {
                                            isLoading = false;
                                          });

                                          if (supir == null) {
                                            showError(
                                                'Gagal mendaftarkan sopir, cek isian kembali!');
                                            Navigator.pop(context);
                                          } else {
                                            supirProvider.supir = supir;
                                            showSuccess(
                                                'Sopir berhasil didaftarkan');
                                            int count = 0;
                                            Navigator.popUntil(context,
                                                (route) {
                                              return count++ == 2;
                                            });
                                          }
                                        }),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    }
                  },
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12, bottom: 12),
                    child: Text(
                      "Daftarkan",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 16,
                          fontFamily: 'PoppinsSemBold'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is to wrap Navigator.push() in async method/function and wait for result

```
void goToTambahSopir() async {
  bool? isUploaded= await Navigator.push();
  if( isUploaded ?? false) {
    _reloadData();
  }
}
```

From TambahSopir you can add result to Navigator.pop();

```
Navigator.pop(context, isUploaded);
```

Comment: I have made like this, but still no change
_reloadData() {
    setState(() {});
  }

  void goToTambahSopir() async {
    bool? isUploaded = await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => TambahSopir(text1: widget.idAngkot.toString())),
    );
    if (isUploaded ?? false) {
      _reloadData();
    }
  }